# PHP - Creating tree node

Tags: php, json, recursion

I am working on a project that uses [jQuery easy ui](http://www.jeasyui.com)

I implemented the tree node but I encountered problems on it. I would like to use the drag and drop feature but I can't produce the right json string.

This is all I have. 
This data was pulled from database :

```
<?php
$array = array( 0 => array( 
                "id"        => 1,
                "text"      => "Root Dir",
                "parent"    => 0
                ),
            1 => array(
                "id"        => 2,
                "text"      => "Folder one",
                "parent"    => 1
                ),
            2 => array(
                "id"        => 3,
                "text"      => "Folder two",
                "parent"    => 2
                ),
            3 => array(
                "id"        => 4,
                "text"      => "File",
                "parent"    => 3
                )
    );
?>
```

the final output should look like this

```
<?php
$array = array(
    "id"        => 1,
    "text"      => "Root Dir",
    "children"  => array(
            "id"        => 2,
            "text"      => "Folder one",
            "children"  => array(
                    "id"        => 3,
                    "text"      => "Folder one",
                    "children"  => array(
                            "id"    => 4,
                            "text"  => "File"
                        )
                )
        )
);
print json_encode( $array );
?>
```

I am willing to adjust the database design if needed.

Comment: I suggest you using a `recursive` function (function that will call itself) for bulding that tree node.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MYSQL Parent Child Same Table; PHP Nest Children Within Parents as a Multidimensional-Array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13888389/mysql-parent-child-same-table-php-nest-children-within-parents-as-a-multidimens)

Comment: thanks guys. @Wrikken thank you so much. I did not saw that.

Comment: Hehe, I was just to lazy to type my answer there again ;)