# How can I get a multi-dimensional array in php from a mysql query containing multiple joins

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have 4 tables that are set up to have hierarchical data. I'm trying to get the data back through a join and find a re-usable way to get a multi-dimensional array from the results which I can potentially use with a different table layout in the future. Ultimately I want to spit it out as json. Is there a good way to do this?

Here's an example of my mySQL code:

```
SELECT 

    table1.name as level1_name,
    table1.id as level1_id,
    table2.name as level2_name,
    table2.id as level2_id,
    table3.name as level3_name,
    table3.id as level3_id,
    table4.name as level4_name,
    table4.id as level4_id

FROM
    table1

LEFT JOIN table2    on table2.parentid      = table1.id
LEFT JOIN table3    on table3.parentid      = table2.id
LEFT JOIN table4    on table4.parentid      = table3.id

WHERE
    table1.id = 5
```

I'd like to see a result like this:

```
Table1_name
{
    Table2_name {
        Table3_name {
            Table4_name,
            Table4_othername
        }
    }
    Table2_othername {
        Table3_othername {
            Table4_othername,
            Table4_otherothername
        }
    }
}
```

But what I'm getting is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [level1_name] => Lorem
            [level1_id] => x
            [level2_name] => Ipsum
            [level2_id] => x
            [level3_name] => Dolor
            [level3_id] => x
            [level4_name] => Eimet
            [level4_id] => x
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [level1_name] => Lorem
            [level1_id] => x
            [level2_name] => Ipsum
            [level2_id] => x
            [level3_name] => Dolor
            [level3_id] => x
            [level4_name] => Eimet
            [level4_id] => x
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [level1_name] => Lorem
            [level1_id] => x
            [level2_name] => Ipsum
            [level2_id] => x
            [level3_name] => Dolor
            [level3_id] => x
            [level4_name] => Eimet
            [level4_id] => x
        )
)
```

Comment: You will not get that from plain `SQL`. Just query for your data, and build the more elaborate construct in PHP. One `foreach` loop should suffice if you can assume the `levelN_names`'s are unique for that level, otherwise you may need the `id` & work with `name` & `children` entries per level.

Comment: I guess I was asking if someone had a class or function that would do this with more abstraction. I can just name everything properly and make it into what I'm looking for but I'll have to re-write it every time the table structures change.

Comment: Well, if you need an entire adjacency list tree, [my answer here works quite well](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13888486/358679), however, for a subtree like the one you are querying it would work less well. I'll think on that a bit...

Answer (score 0):

Either separate your query. Or use a prefix of the field name to add them in different objects
Rename level1_id to level_1_id that way it's easier to parse numbers out using explode and a couple for loops

Answer (score 0):

As others mentioned as well, plain SQL will not get you through this. To produce such an array, you will need to traverse all detail records for each master row.

What you need is a recursive function that constructs the corresponding array for each level of the master/detail hierarchy.

But before that, consider the following:

```
function get_table($table,$field=null,$value=null)
  {
  ....
  }
```

This should return all data from the specified `$table`, in an array of associative arrays, provided that `$field` is `null`. If it is not, it should apply a `where $field=$value` filter.

Now, to the juicy part. The following function will traverse a master/detail table hierarchy, based on the `$details` array and starting with `$table`, possibly filtered by `$field=$value`.

```
function table_tree($table,$arrkey,$details=array(),$field=null,$value=null)    
  {
  $detail=array_shift($details);
  $r=array();
  foreach(get_table($table,$field,$value) as $row)
    {
    $label=$row[$arrkey];
    if($detail)
      $r[$label]=table_tree(
        $detail['table'],
        $detail['label'],
        $details,
        $detail['detailkey'],
        $row[$detail['masterkey']]
        );
    else
      $r[]=$label;
    }
  return $r;
  }
```

Now, the `$details` parameter should be an array of the following form:

```
array(
  array('table'=>..., 'label'=>..., 'detailkey'=>..., 'masterkey'=>...),
  /* etc */
  );
```

There should be an entry for each detail level with the following fields:

- `table`: the detail table name
- `label`: the field that should be used to produce the array keys
- `detailkey`: the field that links the detail row to the master
- `masterkey`: the master table's field, used to filter the detail

For your example, you would need to do something like:

```
$master_table='table1';
$hierarchy=array(
  array('table'=>'table2','label'=>'name','detailkey'=>'parentid','masterkey'=>'id'),
  array('table'=>'table3','label'=>'name','detailkey'=>'parentid','masterkey'=>'id'),
  array('table'=>'table4','label'=>'name','detailkey'=>'parentid','masterkey'=>'id'),
  );
$result=table_tree($master_table,'name',$hierarchy);
```

That's about it. I hope it helps you.