# Create a multidimensional array by processing the same function over and over

Tags: php, loops, multidimensional-array

I am trying to create a multidimensional array of my navigation. All my pages are created in a CMS and then stored in my DB. Each page will have the usual fields like title, url etc but also they will have a field which tells me if it has any children 'p_has_children' as well as a field which will tell me its parent page 'p_parent' (if it is a child of a page).

I thought I could write a function which I could call and send it an array of all the top level navigation items. Then as I loop through each item I would check if it had any children, get the children (and assign them to an array) and then send them through the same function like so....

```
function sideNavArray()
{
    //Get the side navigation
    $getSidenav = $this->crud_model->fetch_rows_where('pages', array('p_side_nav' => 'y', 'p_active' => 'y'));
    //Call the navbuilder function
    $sidenav = $this->sidenavBuilder($getSidenav, 'navitem', 'nav');
    //return the generated nav
    return $sidenav;

}

function sidenavBuilder($navItems, $itemClass, $navLevel, $i = 0, $sidenav = array())
{
    //Loop over each nav item
    foreach($navItems as $navItem){
        //For each item I want to add th nav_title, slug, url and page type
        $sidenav[$i]['p_nav_title'] = $navItem->p_nav_title;
        $sidenav[$i]['p_slug'] = $navItem->p_slug;
        $sidenav[$i]['p_url'] = $navItem->p_title;
        $sidenav[$i]['p_type'] = $navItem->p_type;

        //See if this page has any children
        if($navItem->p_has_children == 'y'){

            //If the page has children then I want to fetch them from the DB
            $subnav = $this->crud_model->fetch_rows_where('pages', array('p_parent' => $navItem->id, 'p_active' => 'y', 'p_protected !=' => 'y'));

            if(!empty($subnav)){

                //Change the item class and level to subnavitem and subnav 
                $itemClass = 'sub' . $itemClass;
                $navLevel = 'sub' . $navLevel;

                //Assign the children to the same array as its parent in the "subnav" level and send it through the sitenavBuilder function
                $sidenav[$i][$navLevel] = $this->sitenavBuilder($subnav, $itemClass, $navLevel);
            }
        }

    $i++;
    //End foreach loop
    }
return $sidenav;
}
```

I am sure some of you are looking at this right now and saying well of course that won't work!

I currently have a navigation being generated but it is on the front end and every time I want to add an additional level I have to go into the code and add it manually. I want to avoid having to write each level of the navigation as I want it to be able to grow to as many levels as it can without me having to go in and code that extra level if it is needed every time.

I hope this all makes sense. Basically I want to know if there is a way to get this nav array to be built by running through the same loop over and over until it doesn't need to anymore.

Comment: [this answer I gave earlier](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13888389/mysql-parent-child-same-table-php-nest-children-within-parents-as-a-multidimens/13888486#13888486) might be worth to take a look at. For one: it will build the tree from the result of only 1 query, and doesn't need recursion.

Comment: Not sure if it's just a typo on here, but 'sidenavBuilder' versus 'sitenavBuilder' could be an issue. Looks like you have a recursive function already, which should work (though that typo makes it not recursive...)

Comment: Thanks Wrikken, I just had a look but wanted to ask would this allow for a nav to grow to say 5 levels deep?

Comment: Michael Wheeler, you have nailed it. Thanks sooo much. I am sure you can appreciate what it's like being so close to the code you can't see the little mistakes. Thanks again.

Comment: @matty: that answer allows it to grow to infinite depth.